# Input must be between 100 and 200 python

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I am creating a program that makes the user enter a number numerous times until said number is between 100 and 200. If the user enters a string or non integer, an error messages is created and the user is prompted to try again. Currently I am having issues with the line:

```
print("You tried " + guesssesTakenInt + "numbers and " + guessesTakenStr +  
   "non-number to get it right.")
```

I assume I have to make it into one while loop, so that the following error: guessesTakenInt is not defined.

```
##
## a6p2.py
##


def main():
    # this is the code that runs when your program is executed
    guessesTakenInt = 0
    guessesTakenStr = 0
    while True:

        guessesTakenStr += 1
        try:
            userNumber = int(input("Please enter a number between 100 and 200: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Sorry that is not a number. ")
            continue
        else:
            break

    while userNumber > 0:

        guessesTakenInt += 1ed

        if userNumber > 200:
            userNumber = int(input("This number is too big. Try again: "))
        elif userNumber < 100:
            userNumber = int(input("This number is too low. Try again: "))
        else:
            guessesTakenInt = str(guessesTakenInt)
            guessesTakenStr = str(guessesTakenStr)

                print("That number is just right!")
                print("You tried " + guesssesTakenInt + "numbers and " + guessesTakenStr + " non-number to get it right.")
                break




    return
    print (main())






###############################################################
## DO NOT CHANGE THIS! LEAVE IT AT THE BOTTOM OF YOUR FILE
## calls the main function when this file is run with Python
##
## python stats.py
##
###############################################################
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: The error is actually "gue***sss***esTakenInt" is not defined. Count the s's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by [JJJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40273582/input-must-be-between-100-and-200-python#comment67806887_40273582), you have a typo there. But that is not all, you also have two different `while`:

1. is used to check if the user typed in a number or not
2. is used to check if the number is in between 100 and 200

---

Here's what you need to do:

1. Both `while` should be merged into one.
2. Use `str.isnumeric()` to test if the string is [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) before parsing it to `int(str)`.
3. Change `guesssesTakenInt` to `guessesTakenInt`
4. Change `guessesTakenInt += 1ed` to `guessesTakenInt += 1`
5. Fix your indentation

---

I took the liberty to change your code.

```
def main():
    # this is the code that runs when your program is executed
    guessesTakenInt = 0
    guessesTakenStr = 0

    user_input = input("Please enter a number between 100 and 200: ")

    while True:
        if user_input.isnumeric():
            user_input = int(user_input)
            guessesTakenInt += 1
            if user_input > 200:
                user_input = input("This number is too big. Try again: ")
            elif user_input < 100:
                user_input = input("This number is too low. Try again: ")
            else:
                guessesTakenInt = str(guessesTakenInt)
                guessesTakenStr = str(guessesTakenStr)
                print("That number is just right!")
                print("You tried {} numbers and {} non-numbers to get it right.".format(guessesTakenInt, guessesTakenStr))
                break
        else:
            guessesTakenStr += 1
            print("Sorry that is not a number. ")
            user_input = input("Please enter a number between 100 and 200: ")

main()
```